# Linking 2010 SQL Native Client 11.0 to SQL Server 2000 for report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, linked-server

I have a legacy system at one of our locations in the US. We currently have a reporting system using SQL Server Report Builder on a central server running SQL Server 2014 using the native client SQL 11.0. I need to build a report using two different remote systems. I have setup linked servers before, but the current issue is that I am trying to setup a linked server to a 2000 server. When I try to make the connection to it it returns an error that native client 11 cannot communicate with SQL Server 2000. I have not found any reliable work around for this, and am trying to see if there is a resolution or solution that can be used.

I was also wondering if maybe a possibility is to create a ODBC connection the SQL server. Then create a linked server to the ODBC, in return that is older version.

- ODBC to SQL Server 2000
- SQL client 11 to ODBC

Is this possible, or a very poor way to handle this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking at this sideways. Instead of insisting that everything goes through SQL Client 11, you should be accessing each individual data source via the best connector. So, just like you wouldn't access an Oracle DB through SQL Client 11, don't try to use SQL Client 11 as your access method for a SQL 2000 DB.  Just use a direct ODBC connection, or an OLEDB connection with a connector that can connect to SQL 2000.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** version - there is 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - take your pick.....

Comment: My apologies. It is 2014. Also going to correct question.

Comment: What i have tried is this. Since the partial data i need is on SQL 2000, and I am trying to link it from SQL 2014. I created a 32 bit ODBC that connects to the 2000 SQL data source just fine. Then trying to now make a linked server connection to the ODBC i setup and linking to that from the SQL 2014 server.  It appears to be functioning, except i am getting a credentials error. Now i am trying to verify the credentials i am using are correct, or if that is a general error for not being able to connect to it.

Comment: 32 bit ODBC connection to the 2000 SQL source returns successful. Trying to now complete the SQL 2014 linked server setup to my 32 bit ODBC.